# Is this a valid sinusoid?

Tags: signal, signal-processing

The given image is from first edition of [this](http://www.amazon.in/Schaums-Outline-Signals-Systems-Edition/dp/0071829466/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1388520893&sr=8-1&keywords=schaums%20signals%20and%20systems) book
[image]

To me the first sinusoid seems valid, in sense that values can be computed at different points.
However, in the case of second sinusoid I fail so see a logic for computing the various values given.
The question is

**Is the second figure valid?**

**If yes, how ?**

Update

It seems I have created much confusion/ambiguity, and I just realized that I didn't use the 'radian' in my calculation for the points of sinusoid( I'm so pathetically used to the 'degree' unit)

What I wished to say was that for the first sampled sinusoid i.e. cosine(pi*n/6) I can, very easily, compute it for n= 1,2,3... and its period, T = 12

For the second case, cosine(n/2), I couldn't compute its values at various 'n' (for the sake of it I didn't/couldn't put in there the 'radian').

Sorry fellows!

Comment: Accepting the first answer after only 6 minutes is a bad idea.  Now you'll never know what other people might have said or even if others generally agree with your accepted answer.

Comment: @OlinLathrop That shouldn't stop you from writing a better answer

Comment: @echad: I'm not saying you answer is bad or that I have a better one.  In any case, my time here is limited, so I usually skip over questions with accepted answers.

Comment: No, neither are sinusoids - surely that is clear - if you wanted to compare to waveforms that are sampled then don't think they can be called sines.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Advise accepted. I must confess that I was in a hurry to get through the concept in these figures( and I was sleepy like *ell). And I also think there was this 'ego' problem, this seems so elementary "How can you not understand it in 2 min ?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are sinusoids, or at least discrete samples of sinusoids.  "Valid" has very little meaning, and is not worth debating about unless you further define it.  The first signal is periodic, the second is not.  If you wish to define a valid sinusoid as being periodic, then the second signal fails that test.  You could resample it such that it will be periodic.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The 2nd graph is not exactly periodic.</strike>

In the second graph, magnitude of X[-5] must = x[7] (this is because the change of n from the local minima is similar), however doesn't.
Similarly X[-7]  must = X[5] if their distance from the local minima is equivalent.

The only time this second graph may be valid is if there's a function that is modulating the amplitude based on the input n  like f(n)cos(n), however here there's only frequency modulation  cos(\$\alpha\$ n)

#### Correction

Second graph is actually valid

Although it doesn't seem periodic due to limited samples. It is symmetric from the origin, and if you calculate it out, the period is at 12.5, which is why there's a X[12] is = x[13] = 1 (roughly).

Comment: It's only periodic at 12.5 if pi is exactly 3.125. Which it isn't. Its period is 4 pi, so it will never repeat exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The sampled sinusoid may look very irregular.
Below example is generated witch Octave:

```
octave:15> x=-13:16;
octave:16> stem(x,cos(x/1.7))
```

[image]

The picture will be even more complex, if we add the phase shift:

```
octave:15> x=-13:16;
octave:16> stem(x,cos(x/1.7-0.5))
```

[image]

However both figures show true sampled sinusoidal signals...

Answer (score -1):

Pi/6 is approx equal to 1/2 so the two plots are valid and scaled to be about the same. What is the context? Something about aliasing? Or phase in sampling? The figures show sines with points calculated at 6 times the Nyquist rate. It is plotted in the typical way for a signal multiplied by a comb function - with the vertical lines representing delta functions. You would not plot points on a simple  sine that way, despite equations shown.